# how to add zoom option in current fancybox effect

Tags: php, html, fancybox

I have gallery page. Onclick image is opening in fancybox. But now i want to add zoom tool(option).SO any attribute or option to add zoom effect in facnybox? My fancyboz version is 2.1.5

Comment: _"May I add it"_ I don't know, I'd have to talk to your boss first... Jokes aside, do please read the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I mean any ready attribute or option for that ?